# How not to extract text when using \includesvg?

Tags: svg, inkscape

When using the `includesvg` macro that is provided by the [`svg` package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/svg) to include an `svg` image, all "text components" of the image (see the [manual](http://ctan.uib.no/graphics/svg/svg.pdf)) are separated into a `pdf_tex` file (which is basically a `tex` file), while the rest of the image is converted into a `pdf` file.

Then the `includesvg` macro somehow merges the `pdf` file and the `pdf_tex` file at the place where the `svg` is included in the document, but the result of this isn't always that great, since when the text components are extracted from the `svg` files, the different font sizes of the different text components are lost and they will all get the same font size in the document they are included in.

**So my question is:** Is there any way when using the `includesvg` macro *not* to extract the text components into a `pdf_tex` file, but put it in the `pdf` file that is generated, in order to preserve the original appearance of the text?

I do realize that it is possible to manually open the svg file in Inkscape and save it as a pdf without using the PDF+LaTeX option and then include the pdf using the `graphicx` package, but I was looking for a way in which includesvg could do this work for you.

Comment: What do you mean by "text"? Does the svg have a `<text>` element? Or a `<foreignObject>` with a text element? Or do you perhaps mean the svg file itself? svg files are made of text...

Comment: The [`svg` package manual](http://ctan.uib.no/graphics/svg/svg.pdf) speaks about a text component, this is what I mean. I will update my question.

Comment: I [found](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/inkscape/trunk/view/head:/src/extension/internal/latex-text-renderer.cpp): "Only PDFLaTeX supports importing a single page of a graphics file, so only PDF backend gets interleaved text/graphics". So maybe try with EPS?

Comment: Why the package svg extracts and the re-embeds the text really baffles me. This "feature" means that the text almost never works right. I'd love to know a solution to this.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `inkscapelatex=false` option.

Behind the scenes, includesvg uses Inkscape's `--export-latex` option, which causes inkscape to generate a PDF without texts, and a LaTex snippet containing all texts, to be included in the document. This allows to put formulae in the SVG, and have them rendered by LaTex on top of the graphics. `inkscapelatex=false` disables this, causing the texts (and fonts, if i remember correctly) to be included int the PDF export.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the reasons this solves the problem?

Comment: Even though the elaboration is lacking, this solved the problem.

Comment: @TeXnician Behind the scenes, includesvg uses inkscape's `--export-latex` option, which causes inkscape to generate a PDF without texts, and a latex snippet containing all texts, to be included in the document. This allows to put formulas in the svg, and have them rendered by latex on top of the graphics. `inkscapelatex=false` disables this, causing the texts (and fonts, if i remember correctly) to be included int the PDF export

Comment: Thanks, that is a good explanation. Please use the edit button to add it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem. In inkscape I've opened svg graphic and changed text object(s) to paths. After that everything was in a place.

Comment: The question stated that he or she knows that it would be possible to open the file and save it as pdf, but wants a solution not involving changing the file. This solution would change the file. This should possibly be just a comment.